# Declaring Const variables

Tags: c++, constants

I plan to use an array ... myarray(row,col)
I want to make both row =3, and col=3
This array will be in

```
myclass{
  private:
        myarray[row][col];
  public:
        void myfunction(); //will use the value of Row & Col
         (Don't worry bout this function, I only put it here
              so you know the variables will be accessed)
}
```

**Q.** I am thinking I should *declare both row & col as const variables,* but I am not sure if they should be declared in or out of the class. They will be accessed by other class functions. I am putting their definition in my cpp file. Anyone's advice is greatly appreciated - Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does the "row" and "col" values need to be available to users of your class? If not then make them private `constexpr` values inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely up to you. It depends how those variables are used  in your program. My personal preference is to make them class members. The reason is to wrap them in the class name space. This way you you can have multiple 'col' and 'row' constants within different classes.

In your case, you must declare them as `static` within the class. The reason is that you use them in a an array size declaration.

For example,

```
class myclass {
public:
    static const int col = 3, row = 4;
    int myarray[row][col];
};
myclass mc1 = new myclass;
... myclass::col ... mc1->row ...
```

You can make them private, if you do not need them outside the class.

There is nothing wrong in making them global. It could be easier to access the constants in some cases. However, it might be more difficult to understand your program by the fellow programmers.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a global MACRO to define row and col like

```
#DEFINE COL 3
#DEFINE ROW 3
```

and then cal use COL and ROW anywhere in the code

Comment: We have the year 2019! Using old c macros is not state of the art anymore. Please consider `constexpr`. And if the OP wants the constants be part of the class, a c-macro will not fit at all!

Comment: I suppose the OP is just starting out considering the simplicity of the question and so they should be more focused on making things work then building the most state of the art terminal program

Comment: We should not offer answers which will be not longer valid, especially if the are looking easy at the first glance. Before we have `constexpr`, a simple `const` inside the class is even better than a global macro. Was a c macro in that case a good solution anytime? I don't believe!